# custom validation - clarification

Tags: javascript

Here is string validation with multiple scenario. Case1 and case 6 are valid scenario other cases are invalid cases.My validation code doesn't work case2 and case5 and case6.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c8t26/5/)

Validation code :

```
function testCases(str){
 return (str.match(new RegExp("\\([^,]+\\)","g")).length == str.split(",").length)
}
```

Actual validation output:

```
stack(2),flow(2),over(4),temp(7): true 
stack(2),flow(3),over(4),temp(k): true 
stack(2),flow(2),over(4),temp(0: false 
stack(2),flow(2),over(,temp): false 
stack(2),flow(2),over(4)temp(8): true 
stack(1),flow(7),over,temp: false
stack(1),flow(),over,temp: false
```

My expectation Output :

```
stack(2),flow(2),over(4),temp(7): true 
stack(2),flow(3),over(4),temp(k): false
stack(2),flow(2),over(4),temp(0: false 
stack(2),flow(2),over(,temp): false 
stack(2),flow(2),over(4)temp(8): false
stack(1),flow(7),over,temp: true
stack(1),flow(),over,temp: false
```

Comment: So to pass validation, parens aren't required, but if they're present, they can only have a number inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your validation code is only checking to make sure that the number of paren groups you have matches the number of terms separated by commas, so it won't do what you want. You should check the terms individually:

```
function validateChunk(s)
{
    return !!s.match(/^[a-z]+(?:\(\d+\))?$/);
}

function filterValid(v)
{
    return !v;
}

function testCases(str)
{
    var chunks = str.split(",");
    var validated = chunks.map(validateChunk);
    return (0 === validated.filter(filterValid).length);

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c8t26/7/

Comment: Actaully in jsfiddle working good. but when i try in below scenario is not working , please advise..catapultacaxi,c907filter(7),accompactor -(true) but method returning as false.

Comment: ah, you didn't mention numbers in the first part; change the `[a-z]` in `validateChunks` to `[a-z0-9]` or `[a-zA-Z0-9]` if uppercase is ok too